# nested d3.json while calling multiple external JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this piece of code

```
var energy = {};
 d3.json("nodes.json", function (nodeData){
d3.json("links.json", function(data){

energy.nodes = nodeData.nodes;
 energy.links = data.links;
     console.log(energy);

 //createChart( energy );   
});});
```

This gives the variable energy value. But when the subsequent function (in comment) is executed, the variable becomes undefined. Could anyone help why and how to fix this?

Comment: When I read your title, I thought you were having trouble with fetching multiple JSON files. But it sounds like the problem doesn't have anything to do with `d3.json`. Nonetheless, I can't see any problem: if `console.log` prints something for `energy`, then it shouldn't be undefined in `createChart`. Could you maybe post the code for `createChart` to verify what's happening?

Comment: Also, this is a great time to use Promises, to avoid the nested callbacks. Get [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), then `var jsonPromisified = Promise.promisify(d3.json); Promises.all([ jsonPromisified("nodes.json"), jsonPromisified("links.json") ]).then(function(results) { energy.nodes = results[1].nodes; energy.links = results[0].links; })`